# Search engines are showing the old URL even after implementing a redirect

Tags: php, redirect, cakephp, seo

I just want to know what code I use in .htaccess file for 301 redirection.

My old URL is `http://www.mercurysolutions.co/training/certified-ethical-hacker-v9-course` and I want to redirect this to `http://www.mercurysolutions.co/ec-council/certified-ethical-hacker-v9-course`

I've tried this code in app/.htaccess and app/webroot/.htaccess both

```
Redirect 301 /training/certified-ethical-hacker-v9-course /ec-council/certified-ethical-hacker-v9-course
```

When I search on search engines related to my company site, it shows the old URL with 404 error. But If I click on that, It redirects to new URL.

Comment: It is working. When I click on your old URL. It redirected me to New URL.

Comment: But not working for search engine...

Comment: but it is showing 302 redirection which is temporary redirection...

Comment: What do you mean `But not working for search engine.`

Comment: I mean to say.. When i search on search engine related to my company site it show the old URL with 404 error. But If I click on that, It redirects to new URL.

Comment: Try `Redirect permanent /training/certified-ethical-hacker-v9-course http://www.mercurysolutions.co/ec-council/certified-ethical-hacker-v9-course`

Comment: NOt working....

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I voted to close this question because general SEO questions are off-topic. Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on Stack Overflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/training/certified-ethical-hacker-v9-course /ec-council/certified-ethical-hacker-v9-course
```

This should redirect your pages.

Search engine is different things. Google has index your old link and shows your old link when searched on search engine. To remove your old link from Google Index from Google WebMaster Tool and should add 410 Gone header so that when Google bot crawls it will notice that the index page has gone.